# How to format js object to php array?

Tags: php, json, string, extjs

So I found some answers on how to do this, but none of them actually worked, i.e. json_decode(). This is what I did:

1. I created js object/array
2. Then I passed it to php file via `Ext.Ajax.Request` as `JSON.stringify(js object)`
3. Now in my php I see the result of that string as follows: `[&quot;James;&quot;,&quot;George;&quot;]`

**I want to get it as an php array like (James, George)**. Any easy way to do this or I have to remove unnecessary parts manually?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should return `["James", "George"]`, not with the `&quot;`.  What is the data going in?

Comment: when you pass ["James", "George"] to php as a parameter, php translates it to string [&quot;James;&quot;,&quot;George;&quot;]. You can see this when you output that string.

Comment: No it doesn't ... or it shouldn't

Comment: It does if you have quotes enabled as @SLaks mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was looking at this problem for a while and finally got the answer.

Inside php, I needed to add **`json_decode(stripslashes($scenarios))`**, where `$scenarios = [&quot;James;&quot;,&quot;George;&quot;]`.

**Code:** ($scenarios is sent from js file via Ajax using JSON.stringify(js object))

```
<?php

$scenarios = empty($_GET['scenarios']) ? false : $_GET['scenarios'];
// more code for validation

$arr = json_decode(stripslashes($scenarios));
?>
```

Now $arr will become regular php array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function

Comment: An example would be helpful too I think.

Comment: @Linus Caldwell without knowing anything about his server-side code it's like `$a = html_entity_decode($b);`. I don't think it's a helpful answer.